# Sharepoint 2010 'Upload To' Libraries

Tags: sharepoint-2010, upload

I am using SharePoint 2010. I want to hide some of "upload to" places when users want to upload pictures to libraries. I basically want to show just specific libraries at that step. Is there a programmatic or any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There only way to achieve this is no remove the library (or users permissions to see it) but this is not a temporary change.